# How to encode a file in FileField using s3 to base64 in django?

Tags: django, base64

I have a project that need to convert the file stored in a model's FileField to Base64 format, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried using `open(model_instance.file_field.file)`, it doesn't work

I tried using `base64.b64encode(model_instance.file_field.file)`, also doesn't work

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Old topic, but just to have some solution here.

```
import base64

encoded_base64 = base64.b64encode(model_instance.file_field.file.read()) # return bytes
encoded_str = encoded_base64.decode('utf-8') # return string
```